# in apache, how to rewrite ".name" to "../ajax/name.php"

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

have all ajax in `../ajax` directory and all `xmlRequest` urls starting with a dot, eg,

```
http://company.com/.call?arg=val
```

would be rewritten as

```
../call.php?arg=val
```

was using handler in php to do the job, but would much rather simply use apache

`mod rewrite.load` enabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not quite consistent with what file path you want rewritten to something else. I am going to assume that you have a file, call.php, located in the "ajax" folder (domain.com/ajax/call.php) and you want this to be called with domain.com/.call

Assuming you have activated the rewrite engine, and know where to put rewrite rules, the appropriate rewrite rule for what you want would look like this:

```
RewriteRule ^\.([aA-zZ0-9]+)(.*)$ ajax/$1.php$2
```

This rewrites anything prefixed with a "." to the ajax-folder and suffixes it with ".php". Additionally, arguments are intact.

Comment: RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.co.com /
RewriteRule ^\.([aA-zZ0-9]+)(.*)$ /data/phiddler/ajax/$1.php$2 /     RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.co.com /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /data/phiddler/http/handler.php / when fed ".test" goes to handler