# Rename URL in Codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, bonfire

I want to remove `/public/index.php` from my Codeigniter and Bonfire project URLs..

My current URL: `http://localhost/public/index.php/page`
Desired URL: `http://localhost/page`

but I want the paths for link and images and robots intact! How does one do that? Any good resources for working with .htaccess?

Comment: try to reading docs/google it first, and tell what you have done ?

Comment: I don't quite understand apache language

Comment: to remove `public` folder you can use vhost, to remove `index.php` you can read the docs. Codeigniter is a good framework because it perfect docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to take following steps:

1. Shift your .htaccess file from application to root directory
2. Remove/comment old code (using #) in old file and paste below code

> RewriteEngine on
> #RewriteBase /
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteRule .* index.php?/$0 [PT,L]
> RewriteRule  ^/?ajax/(.*)$    ajax.php?$1 [NC,QSA,L]

3. Remove index.php from config file against $config['index_page'] like below $config['index_page'] = '';
4. Then activate rewrite module from *Apache*

It should work for you.

Comment: hmmm this works fine but now I have to change every link on all my pages and exclude `public/index.php` any way around this?

Comment: Well, I don't know how many links do you have to change, I think you will have to change them. But for future, you can store critical links in constant.php under config directory as a constant and can use the constant in each source file.

Comment: just one more thing do you mind explaining what is that last RewriteRule? Something about ajax, I found that everything works fine without it

Comment: Well, my apology but I don't know much about .htaccess language, but I change the code according to below link. This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8664480/in-apache-how-to-rewrite-name-to-ajax-name-php

Answer (score 1):

Try reading [CodeIgniter URLs](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html), subsection 'Removing the index.php file':

in the .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

in the config.php :

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Comment: I did doesn't help, as I also need to remove `public/` bit not to mention leave links intact

Answer (score 1):

can you try this?

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /



#Removes access to the system folder by users.

#Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,

#previously this would not have been possible.

#'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]



#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,

#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the

#request to index.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

this works fine on my end

Comment: I get the screen "Welcome to Bonfire v0.7-dev" and I can continue from there but then everything is the same

Comment: have you read codeigniter topic regarding this?
https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html

Comment: or try this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445385/how-to-remove-index-php-in-codeigniters-path/7930935#7930935

Answer (score 0):

You copy the .htaccess file from application i thought into your basedir.

Or add a new .htaccess to your basedir.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: yes I also read the Codeigniter manual however this doesn't work